# Registry.GetValue returns null even though I can see the key in my registry

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying something really simple but I just can't get it to work and wondering why so I thought someone here might have an idea =D

I'm just trying to read a setting from a software that I've installed on my PC by accessing the Registry through Registry.GetValue.

I am using the following (c#) code

```
string key = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CNC Software, Inc.\Mastercam 2023";
var installLanguage = Registry.GetValue(key, "InstallLanguage", null);
```

[image: Regedit Screenshot]

I've seen this exact way used in other projects to access the registry but no matter what I do "GetValue" always returns null. Any ideas?

I've tried running as admin but no change. The OS is 64-bit Win10.

Comment: Is your app 32-bit?

Comment: For some reason I had prefer 32-bit enabled. That was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registry on 64-bit Windows has two different views. 64-bit apps see the native view and 32-bit apps see the 32-bit view by default.

32-bit applications need to change [the view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryview?view=net-7.0) if they want to access the native view when running on 64-bit Windows...